# Magento Cronjob cache configuration

Tags: php, magento, caching, cron

Anyone has experienced change a configuration from magento admin,

clear all cache(including remove the cache folder),

but still load old configuration value from cronjob (if using browser or CURL call, it load the correct configuration)

note:

1. im using nginx + ubuntu + phpfpm in AWS Ec2, mysql is RDS
2. im using cron.sh as magento cron
3. im using magneto custom module with cronjob load old configuration (even core magento configuration value)

Not sure cronjob itself will be cache or not, restart cronjob may help (not yet test), but still dont know the root reason.

Any idea?

---- just test -----

restart cron service not work

restart nginx service not work

restart php-fpm not work

reboot machine work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found that, since **cron job using ubuntu**, then the magento logic will be:

**if** the **var folder** (owner is www-data) is **not writable by current user** (ubuntu)

then **write** it to **/tmp/magento/var/** -- Mage_Core_Model_Config_Options

thus, all old cache store in /tmp/magento/var/, even i **clear the cache from magento backend**, it **will not clear this 'tmp/magento/var'**

above issue can be **resolve** by **update var/ to 777**, **or** **manually delete** the **tmp/magento/var/cache** in stupid way

**however**, if using 777 way, another problem occur:

if the **cron user create a log file that will share with www-data**, the file will be **not writable by www-data (644 by default)**

**another solution** is to change the **cron user as www-data**

**However**

magento is quite special, the cron.sh will call cron.php and cron.php then call to cron.sh again with bin/sh

thus **www-data has no access right to bin/sh**, then i cant use it to run cron

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this method. It should works for your configuration. 
http://www.emiprotechnologies.com/blog/magento-technical-notes-60/post/automatically-refresh-cache-using-cron-in-magento-307